# Spark dataframe requery when converted to rdd

Tags: caching, apache-spark, rdd

I have a dataframe queried as

```
val df1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from table1 limit 1")
df1.cache()
df1.take(1)
scala> Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([10,20151100-0000,B95A,293759,0,7698141.001,8141-11,GOOD,22.01,number,2015-10-07 11:34:37.492])
```

However, if I continue

```
val df2 = df1.rdd
df2.take(1)
scala> Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([10,20151100-0000,B95A,293759,0,7685751.001,5751-05,GOOD,0.0,number,2015-10-03 13:19:22.631])
```

The two results are totally different even though I tried to cache df1. Is there a way to make the result consistent ie. df2 is not going to requery the table again to get the value? Thank you.

Comment: There is no order relation

Comment: For me it is giving the same result. Are you running in the same order? As your query have limit 1 condition, it should not give different row for df2.take(1)

Comment: Does your engine requery the data after df2.take(1)? Actually it doesn't matter take(1) or not. I get the dataframe df1, and want to perform different operations on it. For example, first operation I want df1.rdd.saveAsTextFile(), then another operation I want to perform df1.select(). But it seems like the data I save with the first operation is different from the data I perform select() on.

Answer (score 0):

with `take(1)` you are just taking one random value out of the rdd. When the command is executed, there is no order/sorting specified. As you have a distributed dataset, it is not ensured that you get the same value every time.

You could do a sorting/filtering on the rdd e.g. based on a key (index) or schema column. Then you should be able to always extract the same value you are looking for.

Comment: This is not true. `take(1)` takes the first element of partition 0. For example `sc.textFile("readme.txt").take(1)` will always return the first line of `readme.txt`.